# Is there a way to make Quartus II to support PAL devices?

Tags: vhdl, hdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I use in school the Galaxy to write and compile VHDL programs, but it only runs on Windows XP and I don't have it.

I installed Quartus II in my computer (I use Ubuntu), but apparently there is no support for PAL devices (specifically GAL22V10D). It says that I can install more devices (Tools > Install devices), but it asks me the location of the device files (.qdz) and I can't find it.

Does anyone know where the qdz files are to see if I could search for support for PAL devices?

Or do you know other way (if any) to install support for PAL devices in Quartus II?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: VHDL compilation software is often vendor specific. Altera has Quartus, Xilinx has Vivado, Lattice has Lattice Diamond.

Answer (score 2):

The GAL22V10D is a Lattice device, Quartus II is provided by Altera for Altera devices.

So no, you cannot use Quartus II.